# How to cache an attached Excel file using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a `Product` model that `has_one_attached :file`.

When a Product is created, an excel file is attached to it. Tipically, the excel file needs to be accessed again by another process within 1 hour of the Product being created, so I thought it'd be wise to cache this file so it doesn't have to be downloaded again within that 1 hour timeframe.

I'm currently accessing the attached file like so:

```
product.file.open do |file|
  ...
end
```

But when that happens, I can see the following in the server logs:

```
S3 Storage (1320.9ms) Downloaded file from key: arxnfly66hk6imt7ksa6w1w16
```

There are many caching techniques and I don't know which one would be appropiate for this.

I've tried something like this:

```
product.file.open do |file|
  Rails.cache.write(cache_key, file.read, expires_in: 1.hour)
end
```

But this doesnt seem to work. The `file.read` returns an extremely long string that I don't know how to convert back to an excel file, and either way performing `Rails.cache.read(cache_key)` returns `nil`

If someone can point me in the right directon I'd really appreaciate it.

Comment: The way to cache a file is to save it in a directory on the file system. `Rails.cache` is not intended for this.

Comment: As max said, you're trying to do something that doesn't really make sense. If downloading that file from S3 takes 1 second, how long does it take to process it, or whatever you do with it? Probably longer, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the best way to do this.
Usually I save the file in `tmp` folder, and create a job to delete it after 1 hour

If you want to use cache, you can use

```
File.open(<filename>, "w+") do |f|     
  f.write(Rails.cache.read(cache_key))   
end
```